# Getting one or more files from onActivityResult Intent, and their filenames?

Tags: android, file, csv, android-intent, filesystems

I am using this code to allow the user to select multiple .csv files from their storage:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.setType("text/comma-separated-values");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Get CSV Files"), REQUEST_IMPORT_CSV);
```

After choosing the files it goes to onActivityResult() and so far I have done:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_IMPORT_CSV:
            if (data != null) {
                ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
                ArrayList<Uri> csvUris = new ArrayList<>();
                if (clipData != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                        clipData.getItemAt(i).getText()
                        csvUris.add(clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri());
                    }
                }
                else {
                    csvUris.add(data.getData());
                }

            }
            break;
    }
}
```

1. Is this the right way to get all the relevant Uris from the result? If seems like if the user picks one file, I get the Uri from data.getData(), and if the user picked multiple files, then it goes straight to this clipData() thing instead.
2. Assuming (1) is correct, how do I get the filenames of the corresponding files that the user chose? For example "chosen_file.csv" (I am not asking for the path).

Comment: The file name is the last item in the path if is choosen from primary or secondary storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the right way to get all the relevant Uris from the result?

AFAIK, yes. Leastways, it has worked for me.

> how do I get the filenames of the corresponding files that the user chose?

Strictly speaking, you don't. There is no requirement for the `Uri` to point to a file, any more than the URL to this Web page has to point to a file.

What you *can* do is wrap the `Uri` in a `DocumentFile`, [via `fromSingleUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#fromSingleUri(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)). Then, call `getName()` on the `DocumentFile` to get a "display name" for the content. Depending on where the user got the content from, this *may* be a filename-like value. It is supposed to be something user-recognizable. However, do not assume that it is a filename, as it could be something else.

Comment: The goal is to take the file the user has chosen and see if it's valid (i.e. I am requiring the user to have named the file a specific way -- e.g. it must be of the form "input_data.csv")

Comment: @user7028276: Um, well, then you cannot use the Storage Access Framework. Add [a file-picker library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/35) to your project, and use that. This will not let the user get the file from arbitrary spots on removable storage (since you do not have direct filesystem access to it), or from any other document providers. Your alternative would be to eliminate the mandatory-filename requirement and do something else to validate that the file is what you want.

Comment: "then you cannot use the Storage Access Framework" Why not?

Comment: @user7028276: Because you cannot get a filename from the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and kin), and you want a filename. You can either stop wanting a filename or stop using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: Is there some situation where a user picks a file from their own storage using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and the code I've written above + your `fromSingleUri()` suggestion -- and yet somehow it does not return the filename as desired?

Comment: I suppose it depends on the phone vendor and how they've implemented `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`?

Comment: @user7028276: "Is there some situation where a user picks a file from their own storage" -- the user can choose from any storage provider that they have installed that plugs into the Storage Access Framework. You have no means of forcing them to use a particular provider, and there is no guarantee that the system storage provider (the one that lets the user browse external and removable storage) will reliably return a filename as the "display name". Forcing a magic filename is an obsolete technique.

Comment: `I am requiring the user to have named the file a specific way ` ??? With ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT the user cannot rename a file. Only select existing as is.

Comment: `Because you cannot get a filename from the Storage Access Framework `. Sorry but i have never seen that i did not get the filename when choosing from primary or removable media.